# A question related to contiguity of random regular graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, random-graphs, regular-graph

I am looking for a reference for the following fact. Let $r\geq 3$ be constant, let $G(n,r-2)$ be a random (simple) $(r-2)$-regular graph and let $H(n)$ be an independent random Hamiltonian cycle (on the same vertex set $V=[n]$). Then there exists a positive constant $p_0$ such that, with probability at least $p_0$, the two graphs do not share an edge.

I believe this should follow from contiguity results, something in the spirit of $G(n,r-2)\cup H(n) \approx G(n,r)$. I looked at Wormald [[1](https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/2528/1193.pdf?sequence=1)], which gives several similar results, but I do not see how they imply the particular one above.

Comment: Does $G(n,r)$ contain a Hamiltonian cycle with a probability bounded away from zero? I would doubt that, and if it is not the case, then the last paragraph does not seem to work.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov Yes, with probability approaching $1$ as $n\to\infty$. This was shown in Robinson--Wormald's paper "Almost all regular graphs are Hamiltonian".